# deriving spring state machine from database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-statemachine

Is it possible to store the configuration information for the states, actions, and transitions of the `spring-state-machine` in a database? The idea is to load that configuration data at startup and create the state machine using that data. This way, we can modify the states, actions, and transitions at any time and reload the application to modify the state machine graph.

Secondly, I am a bit confused about the `persist` functionality that the spring-state-machine offers. Is it to persist the history/activity log information in terms of which actions were executed by which user that results in some state transitions? Or is it some internal state of the state machine that helps reload it. If I wanted such activity log available in the database, do the spring-state-machine framework provides the capabilities to store that data?

Answer (score 0):

From the article on [Medium](https://medium.com/@nagillavenkatesh1234/introducing-spring-state-machine-77d446f85e13) it says to configure the state machine

```
@Override
public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States, Events> transitions) 
throws Exception {
    transitions
   .withExternal()
   .source(States.ORDERED)
   .target(States.ASSEMBLED)
   .event(Events.assemble)
   .and()
   .withExternal()
   .source(States.ASSEMBLED)
   .target(States.DELIVERED)
   .event(Events.deliver)
   .and()
   .withExternal()
   .source(States.DELIVERED)
   .target(States.INVOICED)
   .event(Events.release_invoice)
```

So what I think is that if you have a table called tbl_transitions where you have columns

```
id | from_state | to_state | event
-----------------------------------
1  | ORDERED    | ASSEMBELED | assemble
2  | ASSEMBLED  | DELIVERED  | deliver
3  | DELIVERED  | INVOICED   | release_invoice
```

You could read data from this table, loop over it and build your transitions in a "non-fluent" way. I have not given this a try but it is a thought.

Comment: I just found out : https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/html/statemachine-examples-datajpa.html